# How to return to the main JFrame window from a JOptionPane used as a prompt?

Tags: java, passwords

An amateur Java programmer here. Here is the code I'm still working on. My plan is to use a JOptionPane to show if the password entered is correct or not and the attempts left. My problem is that the attempts left doesn't change and the loop goes on and on instead of my plan to terminate if the correct password is entered.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Password extends JFrame {
private static final int WIDTH = 300;
private static final int HEIGHT = 165;
private static final int tries = 3;

private JLabel passwordLabel;
private JTextField passwordTF;

private JButton okB , cancelB;

private OkButtonHandler obHandler;
private CancelButtonHandler cbHandler;

public Password () {
    passwordLabel = new JLabel ("Input password: " , SwingConstants.LEFT);

    passwordTF = new JTextField (25);

    okB = new JButton ("OK");
    obHandler = new OkButtonHandler();
    okB.addActionListener(obHandler);

    cancelB = new JButton("Cancel");
    cbHandler = new CancelButtonHandler();
    cancelB.addActionListener(cbHandler);

    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(null);

    pane.add(passwordLabel);
    pane.add(passwordTF);
    pane.add(okB);
    pane.add(cancelB);

    passwordLabel.setBounds(100 , 0 , 100 , 50);
    passwordTF.setBounds(5 , 40 , 275 , 30);
    okB.setBounds(35 , 75 , 100 , 40);
    cancelB.setBounds(150 , 75 , 100 , 40);

    setTitle("Password");
    setSize(WIDTH , HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}
private class OkButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        String prompt = passwordTF.getText();

        for (int x = 1 ; x<=3 ; x++) {
            if (x==1) {
                if (prompt.equals("Computer")) {
                    passwordTF.setText("");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Access granted" , "Password" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    passwordTF.setText("");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Access denied: "+(tries-1) , "Password" , JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (x==2) {
                if (prompt.equals("Computer")) {
                    passwordTF.setText("");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Access granted" , "Password" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    passwordTF.setText("");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Access denied: "+(tries-2) , "Password" , JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (x==3) {
                if (prompt.equals("Computer")) {
                    passwordTF.setText("");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Access granted" , "Password" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    passwordTF.setText("");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Access denied: System blocked" , "Password" , JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private class CancelButtonHandler implements  ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Password password = new Password ();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use the for loop in this respect, by using

```
continue;
```

it will keep going through the for loop and printing each error message in turn.

As you call the actionListener each time the OK button is pressed, try something like this:

```
private class OkButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    String prompt = passwordTF.getText();
            if (prompt.equals("Computer")) {
                passwordTF.setText("");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Access granted" , "Password" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
            else {
                tries--;
                if (tries != 0){
                passwordTF.setText("");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Access denied: "+(tries) , "Password" , JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
                 else {
                     passwordTF.setText("");
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Access denied: System blocked" , "Password" , JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                     System.exit(0);
                 }
            }
        }
}
```

This will do everything you need it too and then closes the main frame if you enter an incorrect password 3 times.